Top and bottom caption in a tabularray table
Hello guys im new on Latex and I have a problem with a tabularray table.
I want to have 2 captions in one table. Top caption will show a description of a table and bottom caption will show a source description.
This is my actual code:
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{Top caption}
\begin{tblr}{
  width = \linewidth,
  colspec = {Q[300]Q[280]Q[280]},
  cells = {c, valign=m,halign=l},
  cell{1}{1} = {c=3}{0.938\linewidth},
  cell{2}{1-3} = {halign=c},
  hlines,
  vlines,
}
Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum\\
Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum\\
Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum\\
Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum\\

\end{tblr}
\caption*{bottom caption}
\label{table:label_exmple}
\end{table}

And I want to have a table similar like this:
Can you help me please?

welcome! I think the source would be better as a table note. a caption typically has a number etc. not sure about tabularray but threeparttable and threeparttablex are my go-to packages for tabular notes.

\caption is mostly for things like table numbers, \label and the \listoftables.  You can alsways just add text or even images.

Your attached capture suggest that you are using caption to format your table captions.
As an improvement of jlab answer, I suggest using also tblr-extras caption library to use caption package captions with talltblr and longtblr environments
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{labelfont=bf,position=above,skip=6pt}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{tblr-extras}
\UseTblrLibrary{caption}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \begin{talltblr}
            [%
            remark{Source}={Own elaboration},
            caption={Table desciption},
            label={table:label_exmple}
            ]
            {%
                width = \linewidth,
                colspec = {Q[300]Q[280]Q[280]},
                cells = {c, valign=m,halign=l},
                cell{1}{1} = {c=3}{0.938\linewidth},
                cell{2}{1-3} = {halign=c},
                hlines,
                vlines,
            }
            Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum\\
            Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum\\
            Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum\\
            Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum
        \end{talltblr}
    \end{table}
    
\end{document}



Thank u! Can you tell me where you learn more about Latex?

Also, do you know how to change the column height with talltblr?

Do you mean row height?, you can issue a rows = {1cm}, to set all rows to 1 cm or row{1-3} if you want to.change only rows 1 to 3... And so on

thank you again!

The longtblr environment is there for that. Use the key caption for the top caption and remark for the source. You can also set directly the label.
Example:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}
  [%
    remark{Source}={Own elaboration},
    caption={Table desciption},
    label={table:label_exmple}
  ]
  {%
    width = \linewidth,
    colspec = {Q[300]Q[280]Q[280]},
    cells = {c, valign=m,halign=l},
    cell{1}{1} = {c=3}{0.938\linewidth},
    cell{2}{1-3} = {halign=c},
    hlines,
    vlines,
  }
  Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum\\
  Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum\\
  Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum\\
  Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}



Great! thanks - I've deleted my comment.

You are not suposed to put longtblr inside floating environments.

@Mane32 I didn't know, thanks. I edited my answer, I hope it's correct now. Your answer is better: here the talltblr is more suitable. I used a longtblr because in the manual the remark key is documented in this section. I'm sometimes a bit lost with the multiple environments defined by tabularray.

I second for @Mane32 answer (+1).
I must confess that I'm a bit lost in the OP's table code. Therefore just some suggestions, how  the code for your table would be  more correct and simple written:
\documentclass{article}
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage[font=small,
            labelfont=bf,
            skip=1ex]{caption}
\captionsetup{}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{tblr-extras}
\UseTblrLibrary{caption}
         \SetTblrStyle{remark}{\footnotesize}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\begin{talltblr}[
caption={Table description},
  label={table:label_exmple},
remark{Source}={Own elaboration}
                ]{colspec = {*{3}{X[l, m]}},
                  cell{1}{1} = {c=3}{},
                  row{2} = {c},
                  hlines, vlines,
                 }
Lorem ipsum &             &             \\
Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum \\
Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum \\
Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum \\
\end{talltblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}


As you can see, I took a liberty and a wee bit change table style (smaller caption and remark fonts, all column widths are the same).

With {NiceTabular} of nicematrix.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Table description}
\begin{NiceTabular}{X[l]X[l]X}[hvlines]
\RowStyle{\bfseries}
\Block[c]{}{Result} & \Block[c]{}{Result} & Result \\
Result example & Result example & Result example \\
Result example & Result example & Result example 
\begin{TabularNote}
\emph{Source}: own elaboration
\end{TabularNote}
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}


